# My ping sweep program is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a ping sweep program in Python3.

```
import os
import platform
from datetime import datetime

net = input('Enter the network address: ')

net1 = net.split('.')

a = '.'

net2 = net1[0] + a + net1[1] + a + net1[2] + a

st1 = int(input('Enter the starting number: '))

en1 = int(input('Enter the last number: '))

en1 += en1

oper = platform.system()

if(oper == 'Windows'):
    ping1 = 'ping -n 1 '
elif(oper == 'Linux'):
    ping1 = 'ping -c 1 '
else:
    ping1 = 'ping -c 1 '

starttime = datetime.now()
print('Scanning in process...')

for ip in range(st1, en1):
    addr = net2 + str(ip)
    command = ping1 + addr
    response = os.popen(command)
    for line in response.readlines():
        if (line.count('TTL')):
            print(addr, ' ---> Live')
            break

endtime = datetime.now()
totaltime = endtime-starttime
print('Scanning was completed in ', totaltime)
```

Whenever I put in the required inputs it only prints out "Scanning in process" and stays like that until I exit the program. I am on Linux Mint using this on the command line, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: As a first step in debugging, make your code simply print the command instead of executing it and reading the output.  This way you can see what commands it would have executed, and if something is obviously wrong you can see it right away.

Comment: The commands in the for loop print perfectly as they should. I believe it has something to do with the nested loop inside the for loop because whenever i exit it is constantly working on that loop and nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the `ping` commands from the loop work as expected when typed at the command line?  If so, try executing one ping command in an `os.popen()` call in a one-liner python script (i.e. just one call to `os.popen('ping -c 1 foo.bar...')`

Comment: i did this in a python script and it did absolutely nothing (meaning that it worked). should i use the "os.system" command instead of "os.popen"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, there are four problems with your code.

**Pings that fail are taking too long to fail**

On my Linux system (openSuSE), the ping timeout is 10 seconds by default.  It's 5 seconds on Windows.  Your code is probably not hanging, just spending a lot of time waiting for pings to time out.

You can change the timeout of the Linux ping utility by using the command-line parameter `-W` to specify a timeout in seconds.  Note that the timeout must be a whole number of seconds; a timeout of, say, `0.5` will be interpreted as `0` and the ping will appear to wait forever.  On Windows you specify a timeout using the `-w` parameter, but the timeout period is in milliseconds as opposed to seconds with Linux.

**Pings that succeed are not being reported as succeeding**

Here's the output from a successful ping:

```
$ ping -c 1 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.046/0.046/0.046/0.000 ms
```

Look carefully at this output and at the code you use to check whether the target IP address was up.  Notice anything?

Your check for the address being up is in the line `if (line.count('TTL')):`, in other words, you need a line of the output to contain `TTL`.  No lines of the output above contain `TTL`, so your code deems this a failure.

You probably want to check for the string `TTL` appearing *case-insensitively*.  The output doesn't contain `TTL` but it does contain `ttl`.  So try changing `if (line.count('TTL')):` to `if (line.upper().count('TTL')):`.

**Pings that fail are not being reported as failing**

Your code prints out whether pings succeed, but doesn't print out anything if they fail.  I can appreciate that once you've got this script working you might not need it to print out failed pings, but at least while developing and debugging it it's useful to have this information.

Fortunately it's easy to add: add the following lines after `break`:

```
    else:
        print(addr, ' ---> Down')
```

(the `else` should line up with the inner `for`, customise the message as you wish).  The code in the `else` block executes if the `for` loop didn't break, i.e. there were no lines that contained `TTL`.

**You are pinging too many addresses**

Your code contains the line

```
en1 += en1
```

which has the effect of doubling `en1`.

You probably meant to write `en1 += 1`, so that the end address gets included in the loop `for ip in range(st1, en1):`.

Comment: this helped a ton. The missing else statement, the fixing of the en1 += en1 statement as well as the fixing of the if statement in the for loop all made this program work. Very helpful